# Dolphin: Remove 'Open With...' entry from context menu

Tags: dolphin

A recent Dolphin update created an undesirable context menu entry. When performing a right-click on empty space within a Dolphin window, it's first entry says: "Open With..." > "Dolphin"

How can I remove that entry?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the output of `kf5-config --version` and `dolphin --version`?